# Eclipse won't recognize Android Compatibility Javadoc

Tags: android, javadoc

I'm trying to use the v4 compatibility package in an Android application I'm creating, but Eclipse can not seem to find the Javadoc.  I placed the compatibility jar (android-support-v4.jar) in the folder libs, and referenced it in the project build path.  Then I created the Javadoc using

```
javadoc -d docs -sourcepath src\java -subpackages android.support.v4
```

in the console, and that worked fine.  Eclipse says it's a valid Javadoc when I point it to the folder, however on any code I create the uses the compatibility package it just says "This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

```
So the build path for the Javadoc is file:/C:/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/compatibility/v4/docs/
```

It seems to compile fine, but I can't get the Javadoc to show up when I mouse hover.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and am waiting for a new suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to show the javadoc from your compatibility library you can right click your project then click on properties, then on the java build path click libraries and then you will see your android compatibility jar, then click on it and click on source attachment then click on Edit and add your android compatibility path (ie. /android-sdk/extras/android/compatibility)

here is a screenshot for easier guidance: [image: android compat documentation]

Remeber to accept an answer so people can keep answering your future questions.

Comment: I have tried attaching the source and the Javadoc and that does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: +1 Thanks @RayKud, I had similar issue while trying to attach javadoc to support library. but your post helped me. Thank you very much